# How do I remove the empty space at the beginning of a card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this card:

[image]

and I want to make it so the blue box looks like this:

[image]

how would I do this?

my code is this:

```
child: Card(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                title: Text(tasks[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(tasks[index].description, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 1,),
                  leading: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 60.0,
                      width: 10.0,
                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: `ListTile` leaves a space on left for an Icon/Image so it won't be easy to eliminate that leading space.  Height is also likely fixed to 3 lines max (I haven't tested workarounds).  You're prob. best off building yourself a custom widget using `Row` & `Column` and possibly `Stack` to meet your design needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the DevTools here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview

They are super useful especially for when there is something wrong with the layout of your widgets, you can see exactly what is wrong woth that widget.

Im guessing its the SizedBox width:10.